# How to see system variables for Windows 8+ in a better way than the long traditional path?

Tags: windows, operating-system, environment-variables, shortcut

I would like to see environment variables in windows 10 without using the My Computer icon etc. I means, is there some shortcut for this?

Comment: Start `msinfo32`, click on `Software Environment` ->`Environment Variables`

Comment: start, run, cmd & type SET